# run select and update query together

Tags: mysql

Hi
I want to use an update inside of select statement e.g:
`Select * from admin  where id=1 join update data set col1='Mydata'`

the table names and format is not important I want to know it's possible or not? If yes, How?

Comment: @VipulDivyanshu That's not similar to my question! just because they have `select` and `update` , it doesn't mean they're similar!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No it is not possible. you must run them separately

Answer (score 4):

An `update` inside af a `select` statement is not possible.

But...
you can use the `Update`-Statement with specific conditions so the result is the one you need.

Here's a rough example based on your statements:

```
update data, admin
set data.col1 = 'Mydata' 
where data.pkey = admin.pkey
      and admin.id = 1;
```

There should be a link between the two tables which I assumed as "pkey". To be more precise one needs to have a look at the table definitions.

Answer (score 0):

You may be able to use JOIN and a WHERE clause in your UPDATE statement. But, you would need to have some way of joining the two tables.

```
UPDATE admin,data SET data.col1='MyData' WHERE admin.id=1 AND admin.id = data.admin_id;
```

Or something along those lines. Not sure what your tables look like. Read about the UPDATE statement in the reference manual for your database.